# Using An NSString to try to access a UIView

Tags: objective-c, algorithm

I'm working on a little quiz app, and I was working on an algorithm to quickly proceed to the next question. The first part of the code was adequate. It worked well, but the last line threw an error. I was wondering if you could use an NSString to access a UIView variable. Here's the code:

```
NSString *QuestionString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", Question]; // THE "Question" VARIABLE IS AN INT...
NSString *PlayViewString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"PlayView"];
NSString *ThePlayViewString = [PlayViewString stringByAppendingString: QuestionString];
NSLog(@"%@", ThePlayViewString); //WORKS GREAT TO HERE (Logged to make sure everything went well)

self.view = ThePlayViewString; // THROWS ERROR "Incompatible pointer types assigning from 'UIView *' to 'NSString *'"
```

### UPDATE

The algorithm is inside a IBAction for a UIButton. It's meant so that whenever you press the button, or in further questions any other object, you'll proceed onto the next question. Thank you all for establishing that I CAN NOT use a NSString to get to a UIView.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ok, perfect was exaggerated. It worked... satisfactory. I'm trying to proceed to the next question of a quiz by using this algorithm. It takes the number, adds it to the other string, and comes out to equal the same variable as the UIView. I'm trying to make this more efficient than multiple if statements.

Comment: Please update your question with your actual question. Your comment here bears no relation to the content of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its quite clear what happens..

1. `NSLog(ThePlayViewString, @"%@");` iplain wrong way round, it should be
   `NSLog(@"%@",ThePlayViewString, );`
2. `self.view = ThePlayViewString;` gives you the error `"Incompatible pointer types assigning from 'UIView *' to 'NSString *'"`

from this error it should be absolutely clear what is wrong. `self.view` is of type `UIView *` and if you want to assign something to it, it has to be of type `UIView *` as well. you cannot assign a string to a view.

**Solution**:

if you do not know how to create a view, this is where to look: [create a view programmatically](http://chris-software.com/index.php/2009/04/29/creating-a-view-programmatically/)

you could create your views with .xib files (interface builder), name them after your questions and open them with the string, like that:

```
self.view = [[UIView alloc]initWithNibName:ThePlayViewString bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
```

**Edit for your purpose:**

i would use another approach to what you are trying to do.

1. put all questions in an NSArray like that

   NSArray * array = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects: @"question 0", @"question 1", ..., nil];
2. get your question number as before
3. get the next question

   NSString *nextQuestion = [[array objectAtIndex: questionNumber]]; (questionNumber must be type int)

and display it in a label:

```
UILabel *mylabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
[mylabel setText:nextQuestion];
```

i would use interfacebuilder to make a label with a connection.
sebastian

Comment: Thank you! I think that'll be my best bet since I already use .xib files to build my applications. Should I have multiple .xib's for each view, or can I still have just one? Sorry, I'm a little inexperienced.

Comment: see my edit (i made it fat), you need 1 view, with 1 viewcontroller. in the viewcontroller you have an outlet 'label' that you can connect to your label in the .xib. then change the text of the label according to your questions.

Comment: and please dont forget to accept an answer so the question gets closed =)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display that string on the screen you need a UILabel as a subview of your view controller's  which can have its text property set to your string.

You can't assign a string to a UIView property, as you have found out.

What you are attempting is covered in the [basic iOS tutorial from apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhone101/Articles/00_Introduction.html). Have you at least attempted that?

Comment: I've already created an app myself. I go by searching the forums for answers. I teach myself. Thanks for the answer. It's just going to be a pain writing so many "if" statements...

Comment: Asking questions on SO which are easily covered by existing tutorials and documentation isn't "teaching yourself". What do if statements have to do with your question? All you asked about is assigning a string to a UIView.

Comment: I have this all in an IBAction for a UIButton. This way, whenever you press that certain button, it will bring you to the next question.